# Effects of connecting to the database manually in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am coming from a php background background where we remotely connect to the database and manipulate everything with php code. Now in vb.net, will the performance of my desktop application be affected in anyway if i connect manually in the form_load event event instead of vb.net database source connection?

Comment: Too little context, Do your desktop app connects to a remote database, to a database on an internal lan or locally? Which kind of database? With Access/SQLite/SqlServer/MySql the answer could be very different.

Comment: I am connecting to desktop database locally i.e sqlce

Answer (score 0):

i come from both backgrounds.

yes you can manually open database BUT
you should specify the database you are using to make the best performance in your desktop application, for example:

in access database (mdb files), you should open the database once in form_load, and use it all the time, then close it before exitting the application in form_closing (this is for better performance)

while in SQL Server, you should open the database for each function then do your queries then close it after you finish.

Comment: when you have a datareader associated with an opened connection, you can't do anything on that connection until you close the connection. so how can i use only one myconn.open throughout my application?

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataAccessClass.

> Do your db functions in this class (update functions, select functions etc)
>
> Connect to the db on class instantiation.
>
> give your class the necessary work to do, and receive answers back from the class.

In essence, extract your data access from your forms, so that you can reuse your data class anywhere in your app